# Is an array a data type?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, types

Is an array a data type or is it a pointer to its first element?

Comment: No, it's not a matter of opinion.  An array is **not** a pointer.

Comment: @DrewDormann id -> is

Comment: An array is not a pointer nor a data type.

Comment: An array of N elements of type `T` is a type. It's an array type and not an pointer type. Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: a simple difference between array and pointer ! pointer is a variable that can be assigned and array cannot be assigned ! This can prove that pointers and arrays are two different things !

Comment: [This](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/) may help you.

Comment: Types as far as C++ is concerned: http://howardhinnant.github.io/TypeHiearchy.pdf

Comment: @chrk I am sure there is valuable information in your link, but I struggle to take seriously the finer points of arrays and pointers, from an author who can't even use a simple "quote" properly.

Comment: I've voted to re-open this question. I fail to see how it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Asking whether it was a "matter of opinion" in the title rather invited opinion!  Edited.

Answer (score 8):

You're asking about two different languages, C and C++. They happen to have the same rules in this area (mostly), but it's important to keep in mind that they're two distinct (but closely related) languages.

It also depends on what you mean by "an array". It's often best to think of the word "array" as an adjective, not a noun; thus you can have an array *type*, an array *object* (an object of array type), an array *expression* (an expression of array type), and so on.

The C and C++ standards do not define the phrase "data type", though both standards do use the phrase informally a few times. Given the context, it's reasonably clear that the phrase "data type" is synonymous with "object type".

C has two kinds of types, object types and function types. (Prior to the C11 standard, incomplete types were a third kind; the definitions were changed in 2011 so incomplete types are a subset of object types.)

An array *type* is an object type (and no, this is not a matter of opinion).

If you've been told that an array is "really" a pointer to its first element, you've been badly misinformed. An array expression is implicitly *converted*, in most but not all contexts, to a pointer to the array's first element. The array object still exists, is still an object, and is still of array type.

Suggested reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 2):

An array is a type. It can be called a compound type or an array type (C++ standard, §3.9.2):

> Compound types can be constructed in the following ways:
>   — arrays of objects of a given type, (8.3.4)

Where (§8.3.4) is, emphasis mine:

> In a declaration `T` `D` where `D` has the form
>
> ```
>  D1 [ constant-expressionopt] attribute-specifier-seqopt
> ```
>
> and the type of the identifier in the declaration `T D1` is “*derived-declarator-type-list* `T`”, then the type of the
>   identifier of `D` is an **array type**;

And, like any other type, you can use it in a `typedef`. From the same section:

> ```
> typedef int A[5], AA[2][3];
> typedef const A CA; // type is “array of 5 const int”
> typedef const AA CAA; // type is “array of 2 array of 3 const int”
> ```

An object of array type can be *implicitly cast* to a pointer, hence the potential confusion:

```
void foo(int* );
A some_array;

foo(some_array);       // OK
int* p = some_array;   // OK
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is an array a data type or is it a pointer to its first element?

It is a data type and it is **not** a pointer.

## Here's the source of this common confusion.

- An array may be implicitly *converted* to a *pointer to the first element* (but not the other way around)
- A pointer shares some syntactical similarities with arrays (namely "`[]`") so it's not always obvious to beginners when an implicit cast has happened.

Comment: Actually the `[]` operator requires a pointer operand and an integer operand. The pointer needs to point to an element of an array object. `[]` is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic: `a[i]` means `*(a+i)`

Answer (score 1):

Strictly an array in an *instance* of an object having *array type*.  So arrays *have type* rather than *are types*.

While arrays have type (and are an example of container data structure), it is perhaps useful to understand that in C and C++, unlike fundamental types, and `class`/`struct`/`union` types they are not treated as [first-class data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) in that they cannot be passed as parameters by-value, returned by-value, or assigned to or from.

An array is not the same as a pointer - an array in C and C++ has *size* equal to the number of elements multiplied by the size of each element, whereas a pointer is the size of a pointer rather than the size of what it refers to.  However because an array is not a first-class type, when passed, returned or assigned-from, the array "decays" to a pointer.

The C++ STL supports various container data structure types that are more flexible and generally safer than raw arrays, and are first class types.

Comment: An array *type* is clearly a type in both C and C++. There are merely some restrictions on what operations are available for objects and expressions of array type.

Comment: @KeithThompson : Indeed - I have modified the answer, I don't think I was sayimg anything different, but your point was not emphasised.

Comment: *All* types are "data structures"; I don't think emphasizing that point is useful. Bottom line: array types are types. All types are restricted in the operations you can apply to them.

Comment: Sure, there's a clear distinction -- but it's not between "data types" and "data structures". Structures are assignable, and they're generally considered "first-class" types, but they're on the same side of that dividing line as arrays. In any case, the question was whether arrays are "data types"; that's a yes-or-no question that I don't believe you've answered. (Incidentally, the first version of your answer incorrectly said that they're not.) For any reasonable definition of the term "data type", the answer is quite simply yes: an array type is a data type.

Comment: @KeithThompson : Yes but simply saying that adds nothing usful to the conversation.  That fact that the context of C and C++ arrays are in a different category to basic types and structs is worth noting.

Comment: @KeithThompson : My apologies, I deleted the comment you were referring to.  It was not my intention to suggest that data structures != first-class type.  The fact that arrays are both data structures and not first-class types are independent not causal observations.

Comment: Adds nothing useful to *what* conversation? **That was the question**.  If you want to discuss the second-classness of array types without talking about whether they're "data types", I suggest you find some place other than an answer to a question asking whether arrays are data types. Or at least answer the question *and then* discuss side points.

Comment: @KeithThompson : I think we are in somewhat violent agreement - I am more than willing to have you edit the question to render the semantics to your taste (if it is really that offensive I can delete it).  I merely used the term "conversation" to refer to the question and its answers on aggregate I could not think of a better term to convey that - *discourse* perhaps?  The question itself has already been deemed out of bounds, apparently because it canvasses opinion, though it is not a matter of opinion in your view; but the direct answer is certainly of little interest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69620/discussion-between-clifford-and-keith-thompson).